# match timestamp with date in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, group-by

I have a table

```
id user     Visitor timestamp
13 username abc     2014-01-16 15:01:44
```

I have to 'Count' total visitors for a 'User' for last seven days group by date(not timestamp)

```
SELECT count(*) from tableA WHERE user=username GROUPBY __How to do it__ LIMIT for last seven day from today.
```

If any day no visitor came so, no row would be there so it should show 0.

What would be correct QUERY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to `GROUP BY` resultset, you need to count visits for a week (with unspecified user). Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    `timestamp` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

If you need to track visits for a specified user, then try this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(`timestamp`) as `date`,
    COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    (`timestamp` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY))
    AND
    (`user` = 'username')
GROUP BY
    `date`;
```

[MySQL `DATE()` function reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Comment: the user want to count visits of each day

Comment: and still not for each day separately , спасибо :)

Comment: @AlirezaFallah fixed, again. Не за что (:

Comment: @HAL9000 - I need VISITOR count for each day of the week
e.g. - 1 jan - 300 , 2jan -398, for next 7 days,
GROUPBY with timestamp will not solve the issue, I need to group by date

Comment: @AkashKumar Have you tried the second query, that I've provided ?

Comment: 2nd query Worked fine Thanks, Is there any way to make COUNT=0 for the date which is not present in table

Comment: @AkashKumar Yes, however, this is another question.

Comment: @HAL9000-
Here is the new question please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302897/make-visitor-count-for-the-day-equal-to-0-which-is-not-present-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(a.timestamp), COUNT(*) 
FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.user='username' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(a.timestamp)) <= 7
GROUP BY DATE(a.timestamp);
```

Comment: Worked fine Thanks, Is there any way to make COUNT=0 for the date which is not present in table

Comment: The way you constructued the WHERE condition will kill the usage of indexes. Instead, use `a.timestamp` clear: DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) >= a.timestamp

Answer (score 0):

i think it's work :)

```
SELECT Count(*) 
from table A 
WHERE user = username AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),timestamp)<=7
```