# make visitor count for the day equal to 0 which is not present in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a table

```
___________________________________________
id |   user  | Visitor | timestamp
___________________________________________
13 |username |abc     | 2014-01-15 15:01:44
14 |username |abc     | 2014-01-15 15:01:44
15 |username |abc     | 2014-01-18 15:01:44
16 |username |abc     | 2014-01-18 15:01:44
___________________________________________
```

I used QUERY to COUNT no of visitor of USER abc for last 7 days from TODAY.

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) as `date`, COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `table` WHERE (`timestamp` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND (`user` = 'username')
GROUP BY `date`;
```

It get following output:

```
______________________________
date              |  count
______________________________
2014-01-15        |     2
2014-01-18        |     2
```

But I need:

```
______________________________
date              |  count
______________________________
2014-01-15        |     2
2014-01-16        |     0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2014-01-17        |     0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2014-01-18        |     2
```

***What will be query for this?***

Comment: Cant you do this with PHP? As you will loop from lower milt to date to higher limit and what ever date you do not found in the range, print 0 count for that.

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled in the presentation layer/application-level code, if you have that (e.g. A simple PHP loop - although you can also fake the start and end dates with a UNION). Otherwise, construct a calendar table and join to that.

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquer to create a table with all the days in the past week, then join that with your table:

```
SELECT `date`, IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as `count`
FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS `date`
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 DAY))
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))) AS days
LEFT JOIN `table` ON DATE(`timestamp`) = `date`
WHERE (`timestamp` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND (`user` = 'username')
GROUP BY `date`;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a well-known problem about [gap](/questions/tagged/gap) - and it has many answers on SO.

First, most obvious way - is to use table that will hold all dates consecutive (for current year as a sample) For example, let it be `dates` table with field `record_date` (it holds date) then your query will look like:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`timestamp`) as `date`, 
  COUNT(`dates`.`id`) as `count`
FROM 
  `dates`
  LEFT JOIN
    `table`
      ON `dates`.`record_date` = DATE(`table`.`timestamp`)
WHERE 
  (`timestamp` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) 
  AND 
  (`user` = 'username')
GROUP BY 
  `dates`.`record_date`
```

-so you'll force returning zeros via `LEFT JOIN`.

There is another, more complex way, to achieve this with sequence generator query. Actually, there are no sequences in MySQL, but you can generate consecutive values from `CROSS JOIN` and then apply them to date selection. For example:

```
SELECT
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, INTERVAL sequence.id DAY)
FROM
(SELECT
 (two_1.id + two_2.id + two_4.id + 
 two_8.id + two_16.id) AS id
 FROM
 (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id) AS two_1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id) AS two_2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id) AS two_4
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS id) AS two_8
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 16 AS id) AS two_16
 ) AS sequence
WHERE
  sequence.id<7
```

-will will [produce dates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a198/2) for previous week, so you'll be able to use this instead of creating and filling temporary table like in first way. Good thing about this query is - that it's static, thus you'll not have to add another `UNION` part if you'll want to increase selection interval.

Comment: 'current year'? Why not a table with all dates *ever*? It will be tiny!

Comment: @Strawberry that was a sample. And, yes, it's described as "most obvious" way. In any case, with using second query it's possible to get dates for any interval (and without additional tables or changing query itself)